# Hover a button/link to get dropdown with materialize.css alpha.3

Tags: materialize

I am using `materializecss` to hover a button to get drop down menu. But i am not able to achieve this using Alpha-1 version.

```
<!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
  <a class='dropdown-trigger btn' href='#' data-target='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>

  <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
  <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
    <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">view_module</i>four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>five</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Working Demo Here :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.dropdown-button').dropdown({
      hover: true, // Activate on hover
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    
    
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.3/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  
  <a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#' data-target='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>

  <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
    <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">view_module</i>four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>five</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i want `on-hover` with `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.3/css/materialize.min.css` CDN